# Caesar cipher in c++

Tags: caesar-cipher

I'm having a problem figuring out what the errors that I am getting from running my program mean. I am trying to do a Caesar cipher program. There is also a header file that has most of the constants and the functions declared.

The errors that I'm getting are:

```
In file included from proj1_test_public.cpp:62:
proj1.cpp: In function ‘int test_main()’:
proj1.cpp:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
proj1.cpp:16: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char SolveCipher(const char*, char*)’
proj1.cpp:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’
proj1.cpp:16: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘char SolveCipher(const char*, char*)’
proj1.cpp: In function ‘void Decipher(char*, char)’:
proj1.cpp:41: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer     expressions
proj1.cpp: In function ‘char SolveCipher(const char*, char*)’:
proj1.cpp:67: error: invalid types ‘const char[int]’ for array subscript
proj1.cpp:73: error: invalid types ‘const char[int]’ for array subscript
make: *** [proj1_test_public.o] Error 1
```

Line 16 is where it says "char mess=SolveCipher(globeCip[i],dec_message[i]);"

Line 41 is just a warning but it works (it is in the decipher function)

Line 67 is where it says "if(Decipher(cip[k][l],keyin)==cribs[k][l])"

Line 73 is where it says " dec=Decipher(cip[k][l],keyin);" under the else statement in the second for loop.

Header file code:

```
#ifndef PROJ1_H
#define PROJ1_H

const int ALPHALEN   = 26; // number of valid characters (A-Z)                                                                             
const int MAXMSGLEN  = 60; // maximum message length                                                                                       
const int NUMMSGS    = 10; // number of messages                                                                                           
const int NUMCRIBS   =  5; // number of     cribs                                                                                              
const int MAXCRIBLEN =  8; // maximum crib length   



const char cipher[NUMMSGS][MAXMSGLEN] = {
  "HAAHJR HA KHDU AVTVYYVD",
  "DHFGS NBKNBJ ZMC ZKK HR VDKK",
  "Q PIDM JQMJMZ NMDMZ",
  "JCTFGT DGVVGT HCUVGT UVTQPIGT",
  "LRPYE I HTWW XPPE JZF LE ESP NZXXZYD",
  "KLSQ GML LGG DSLW YGL FGLZAF AF EQ TJSAF",
  "QEBC GUR ZVPEBSVYZ ORUVAQ GUR FGNGHR",
  "GZSGZWD NX XTRJBMJWJ JQXJ FY UWJXJSY",
  "RZVOCZM AJM OJHJMMJR HJMIDIB RVMH RDOC GJR XGJPYN",
  "ROBO MYWO LKN XOGC DKVUSXQ DRSC KXN DRKD"
};

const char cribs[NUMCRIBS][MAXCRIBLEN] = {
  "ATTACK",
  "MEET",
  "DROP",
  "AGENT",
  "WEATHER"
};

void Decipher(char cip[], char key);

char SolveCipher(const char cip[], char dec[]);
#endif
```

Main file's Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "proj1.h"
char globeCip[MAXMSGLEN];

int main()
{
  char dec_message[MAXMSGLEN];

  for(int i=0; i<=NUMMSGS; i++)
    {
      strncpy(globeCip,cipher[i],MAXMSGLEN);
      char mess=SolveCipher(globeCip[i],dec_message[i]);
      if(mess=='\0')
        {
          cout<<"Message #  "<<i<<": was not interesting "<<endl;
        }
      else
        {
          cout<<"Message #  "<<i<<": "<<mess<<endl;
        }
    }

  return 0;
}



void Decipher(char cip[], char key)
{

  for(int j=0; j<strlen(cip); j++)
  {
    if(cip[j]-key<'A')
      {
        char diff=(key-'A')+key;
        cip[j]=(cip[j]-key)+diff;

      }
    else
      {
    cip[j]=((((cip[j]-65)-key)%26)+65);
      }
  }


}
char SolveCipher(const char cip[], char dec[])
{
  char keyin='A';
  for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
      keyin=keyin+i;
    }
  for(int k=0; k<NUMMSGS; k++)
    {
      for(int l=0; l<MAXMSGLEN; l++)
        {
          if(Decipher(cip[k][l],keyin)==cribs[k][l])
           {
              return '\0';
            }
          else
            {
              dec=Decipher(cip[k][l],keyin);
            }

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: `globeCip[i]` is going to the character stored at `*(globecip + i)`, basically, not a pointer to a character. but in the function you've defined the argument as being a pointer-to-char. hence the error: cannot convert char to pointer-to-char.

Comment: So then, what should I do?

Comment: change your function to accept a single character, instead of an array-of-characters. you're basically saying "this function accepts oranges", then stuffing in an apple and asking why it's not working.